# Datas dos posts em formato estranho (ex: "9/06y2014" para 9 de junho de 2014), mas somente para posts antigos

Tags: bug, status-pronto, interface-usuário

Muitas datas estão aparecendo em um formato estranho em várias páginas.

Por exemplo, [nesta pergunta de 2014](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/112052), aparece assim:

- perguntada **9/06y2014** às 18:08
- editada **24/09y2015** às 17:45

[image: SOpt: datas em formato errado]

Nas respostas acontece o mesmo, antes do ano tem um "y".

Reparei que isso só acontece no SOpt. No SOen, por exemplo, [esta pergunta de 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11906056) mostra as datas no formato correto:

- asked Aug 10, 2012 at 16:53
- edited Jan 29, 2019 at 15:11

[image: SOen: datas no formato correto]

---

Quando a data não é tão antiga, isso não acontece. Por exemplo, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/541365/112052), feita em janeiro deste ano, aparece assim:

- perguntada 28/01 às 14:35
- editada 31/01 às 20:28

[image: SOpt: datas deste ano ficam corretas]

E quando feita no mesmo dia, também fica correto, já que o formato é diferente. Por exemplo, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/543194/112052):

- perguntada 5 horas atrás
- editada 2 horas atrás

[image: SOpt: perguntas recentes ficam com data correta]

---

Ou seja, o problema parece acontecer somente quando o ano da data é menor ou igual ao ano passado.

E tem outras páginas com o mesmo problema. Por exemplo, vendo as [respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=50) do meu perfil:

[image: Página de respostas do meu perfil]

E as [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo?tab=questions):

[image: Página de perguntas do meu perfil]

Nesta última podemos ver que o problema não ocorre com datas deste ano.

Outras páginas com o mesmo problema: histórico de reputação, favoritos/bookmarks, recompensas e posts que sigo (todos estes são links do perfil), resultados da busca, e a [própria lista de perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions) (seja da Home, ou [de uma tag específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array?tab=newest&page=5&pagesize=50)).

Tanto o site principal quanto o Meta estão assim.

Comment: Alguém deve ter feito lambança numa string que define formato de data :P

Comment: Apenas para adiantar, já solicitei a revisão, agora vamos aguardar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Parece que foi corrigido...

Comment: Eu ia adicionar a tag, mas o @JNat foi mais rápido :)